# typescript Cannot find name variable declare at class level inside function within same class

Tags: function, class, variables, typescript, interface

Need advise on the following code which i am trying to learn. I am using typescript 1.8.10 compiler and EM5:

```
module myAwersome.module{
    'use strict';
    export interface INavigateService {
            links: string[],
            getLinks():void
            }
    class Test implements INavigateService  {
            links:string[] = [];
            getLinks():void {
                links.push("hello world"); //ERROR unable to find name links 
            }
}
```

Comment: Solved by using this.links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access class members, you must do so through the `this` keyword:

```
this.links.push("Hello world");
```